# Auth Component, Controller other than Users

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I don't have a User table. I got a Customer table. It seems like Cakephp Auth doesn't recognise any other table beside User. Is there any way to walk around this error?

If I tried using `$this->Auth->User('role')` - it works perfectly fine. But all my auth credentials is under the Customer table. please help.

I got this error below

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method AuthComponent::Customer() in
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/development03/app/app_controller.php on line 56
```

The code:

```
function beforeFilter() {
    $this->set('admin', $this->_isAdmin());
}

function _isAdmin() {
    $admin = FALSE;
    if ($this->Auth->Customer('role') == 'admin') {
        $admin = TRUE;
    }
    return $admin;  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's say that you want administrators table where **username** is field **email** and **password** is field **password**:

In your AppController.php:

```
public $components = array('Session',
        'Auth' => array('authenticate' => array('Form' => array( 'userModel' => 'Administrator',
                                                         'fields' => array(
                                                                              'username' => 'email',
                                                                              'password' => 'password'
                                                                              )
                                                            )
                                            ),
                'authorize' => array('Controller'),
                'loginAction' => array('controller' => 'administrators', 'action' => 'login'),
                'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'Home', 'action' => 'index'),
                'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'Home', 'action' => 'index'),
          ),             
    );
```

In AppController.php add this too:

```
public function isAuthorized($user){
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `userModel => ModelName` property. Your AppController should looks like:

```
class AppController extends Controller
{    
    public $components = array(
        'Auth' => array('authenticate' => array('Form' => array('userModel' =>'Customer', 
                                                                'fields' => array('username' => 'USER_LOGINNAME', 'password' => 'USER_PASSWORD'
                                                                             )
                                                            )
                                            )
                    )
);
 /*...... Your code ............*/
}
```

[This link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers) might help you to resolve bugs.

Comment: btw i am still using cakephp 1.2 var `$components = array('Session', 'RequestHandler', 'Shop', 
        'Auth' => array('authenticate' => array('Form' => array('userModel' =>'Customer', 
                                                                'fields' => array('username' => 'USER_LOGINNAME', 'password' => 'USER_PASSWORD'))))` i am still getting this error Fatal error: Call to undefined method AuthComponent::Customer() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/development03/app/app_controller.php on line 65